# Dynamically Updating A Tab Bar Item In the More ViewController Table

Tags: swift, uitabbarcontroller

OK. I haven't actually seen how to do this anywhere. It may be a question of "You can't get there from here." or "Holy #@$! That is such a disgusting hack it should be taken behind the woodshed and shot!".

I have a tabbed Swift 3 iOS app that will dynamically update the Tab Bar images of selected pages as the page state changes.

I do that sort of like this:

```
if let navController = self.navigationController as? MyNavController {
    navController.tabBarItem.image = navController.tabBarImage
    navController.tabBarItem.selectedImage = navController.tabBarImage
}
```

The tabBarImage is actually a calculated property. This snippet is called within a UI callback that updates when the state changes.

This works great.

When in the MoreViewController, though, not so great. Those images remain stubbornly static, no matter what I do.

I have done some exploration of the MoreViewController. I can get at the tableView and the cells, but that smells like the kind of hack that will get my app taken behind the woodshed by the Blue Meanies at App Review.

Is there a proper way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK. I figured out how to do it.

I was crawling back along the navigation controller path; which worked fine for items not in the more space.

I fixed it by crawling forward from the tab bar controller, instead:

```
self.tabBarController?.viewControllers?[MySelectionIndex].tabBarItem.image = self.tabBarImage
self.tabBarController?.viewControllers?[MySelectionIndex].tabBarItem.selectedImage = self.tabBarImage
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Notification and pass the images within a Dictionary as a Notification object. Then you can get different tabBarImage with different key value at once.

Comment: Thanks! Where would I send the notification? The MoreTabBarController?

Comment: You could send notification from anywhere, not only MoreTabBarController. Since notification could be received from each controller, which adds observer on that notification.